# How to backup the database from the server to the client computer using asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used code C # to write one page of data to back up the .bak file from the server to the client machine. when I tested on my computer is very good. which when connected through another computer by using connectionString web.cofig it reappears errors like this. This one was like before or workaround, please help.

[image]

private string _ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FillDatabases();
        //ReadBackupFiles();
    }
}

private void FillDatabases()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        ddlDatabases.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
        ddlDatabases.DataTextField = "name";
        ddlDatabases.DataValueField = "database_id";
        ddlDatabases.DataBind();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = sqlException.Message.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = exception.Message.ToString();
    }
}

protected void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string _DatabaseName = ddlDatabases.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        string _BackupName = _DatabaseName + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".bak";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        string sqlQuery = "BACKUP DATABASE " + _DatabaseName + " TO DISK = 'D:\\SQLServerBackups\\" + _BackupName + "' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups', NAME = '" + _BackupName + "';";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int iRows = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
        lblMessage.Text = "The " + _DatabaseName + " database Backup with the name " + _BackupName + " successfully...";
        ReadBackupFiles();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = sqlException.Message.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = exception.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code and more details

Comment: the error says it all, file path was incorrect

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Where is your ReadBackupFiles() method?

Comment: On dev, is your sql server and site on the same machine? Are they maybe on separate machines when deployed?

Comment: on the server and the client

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is when you run this program on your computer everything works right because it's setup for your system. If you want to transfer to your system or another computer separate from the server there are a couple of things that might work. You can make a shared drive off the system you want the program to drop the files in, which may or may not work since share folders are treated differently then normal folders/drives. I would write a upload program that connects to a file server and uploads the backup files to there automatically, after the server dumps to a predefined folder that the server has access to. There are some really good file upload libraries available to C# that can automate this process for you. So you can have an asp.net page that puts the backup file like it does for your system currently, and another c# program that is setup to run at a certain time using scheduler and uploads the backup to your desired location remotely from the server.

Hope this makes sense, let me know if you have any questions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is the code to have C# upload files automatically for you from a file location. You'll need to setup a ftp server on the computer you want the backups to go to. Otherwise the only way around this is to make the files available for download off the sever in question which means just making the folder visible to the Internet. But I'd go with the ftp options since it's the most flexible.

Comment: So now there are any other solutions? guided me to webservice for when backup data on the server, the backup .bak file in the folder is will the client. but I do not understand how to do this very well. Can you help me?

Comment: Sure! Can you add the code that does that .bak dump to your question above? I'll look for the FTP upload program that will help to automate the upload process. Kinda like a round about way of doing a cron job with a bash script. But it will help me understand how you were doing the backup on your system if I can see the code in the question. I'm going to bed soon so I may not get back to you until the morning.

Comment: But also the program is saying the drive is incorrect. So this maybe an misunderstanding on my part. Did you make sure the drive and folder location excited on the system you pointed the program too? It sounds to me like the program was written on your system and then moved to the server and there stopped functioning. So there maybe a misunderstanding on my part. So some more clarification will help me out.

Comment: Say thank you for sharing your but. I have to add code. you can treat yourself and the answer is no?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. But you are using the file location incorrectly in your code, that is saving the file to a location on the server that is 'D:\\SQLServerBackups'

Answer (score 0):

You create backup in online-mode or just have in your server? If you have some files in your server, realize downloading function and that's all what you need.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/backups/"+file)); //backup must be located in folder in your application folder, that folder named *backups*
Response.End(); //file is a filename of your backup: e.g. 20151224.bak
```

If you create backup online and want to send it to user, you have to do next steps (it is just one approach):

1) Make backup and save it into your application folder to some temporary folder

2) Realize download page as I show earlier (user will download it)

3) And as soon as user download that, you will just delete your temporary backup file.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you !
but this is almost like a backup on the server that is already in there .bak file copy on it.
so they themselves will not. I wanted to like the backup on files stored on the server in the user's computer only. rather than through manipulation stored in the server hard drive and then copy the user's computer

anyway thank you very much. because you have given me more 1 way is also good